# How to get textbox date formatted as a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

I am using a textbox with text mode set as date. What I need is to arrange the date format to MM/dd/yyyy. I know if I use `DateTime.Now`, it gets today's date, but I cannot get the value of user's picked date if I do like this as there is error:

```
string dateOfBirth = DateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

This is how I do:

```
string tmpDateOfBirth = tb_date.Text;
//This below line returns todays date and not the date that the user pick on the calendar.
string dateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: _This returns todays date.._ Could be because of `DateTime.Now` ?

Comment: What error are you getting? Please be more speciffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using today's date and formatting it... You need to format what has been entered in your textbox.

```
string dateOfBirth = tb_date.Text.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

EDIT : if you are getting 'best overloaded match error'

```
string dateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(tb_date.Text).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @Shah You get `best overloaded match error` when the variable isnt a string. Your textbox is probably containing a DateTime object. You will have to parse it's text.

Comment: @Shah `string dateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(tb_date.Text).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks.This is the right one string dateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(tb_date.Text).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here i assume your TextBox1.Text contain valid date value. So below code might help you.

```
string dateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", 
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the user picking the date?
If you have a DateTimePicker object, you can just type

```
string dateOfBirth = MyDateTimePicker.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

**EDIT**

Textboxes are not meant to hold `datetime` objects. If you need to do so, you'll have to parse its text:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("TextBox1.Text", "MM/dd/yyyy", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: i dont have a DateTimePicker object.Its a aspn.net text box with text mode set to date

Comment: If your textbox has the "MM/dd/yyyy" format already, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the selected value of `DateTimePicker`.

Try this:

```
string datetime = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("DateTimeFormat");
```

See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx